# Java - Differenciate between two Strings sent into OustputStream

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

- I'm sending 2 String values into an OutputStream from the Client.java as follows :

  ```
  outputStream.write(username.getText().getBytes());
  outputStream.write(password.getText().getBytes());
  ```
- In the Server.java, i'm trying to get each value separated, when i read the inputStream :

  `inputStream     =   s.getInputStream();
   byte[]username  =   new byte[20];
   inputStream.read(username);
   String user     =   new String(username);
   System.out.println("username = "+user);`

i get logically : `usernamepassword` as the console output.
what i want to do is :

```
     String usr = new String(user);
     String pass = new String(password);
```

**Is there a better way to do it than adding some delimiter in the outputStream String ?**

Comment: Almost certainly not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delimit the two string values so the reader knows where one string ends and the next string begins.  What that delimiter actually consists of is up to you to decide based on your particular needs.

1. You could write out a string's byte length using a fixed-width integer before then writing out the actual bytes. The reader can then read the length first before then reading the specified number of bytes that follow:

   ```
   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
   byte[] bytes;
   int len;

   bytes = username.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   len = bytes.length;
   dos.writeInt(len);
   dos.write(bytes, 0, len);

   bytes = password.getText().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   len = bytes.length;
   dos.writeInt(len);
   dos.write(bytes, 0, len);
   ```

   ```
   inputStream = s.getInputStream();
   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
   byte[] bytes;
   int len;

   len = dis.readInt();
   bytes = new byte[len];
   dis.readFully(bytes);
   String username = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

   len = dis.readInt();
   bytes = new byte[len];
   dis.readFully(bytes);
   String password = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
   ```

   Alternatively, `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` can write/read `String` values directly, handling the above logic internally for you (using a `short` instead of an `int` for the length value):

   ```
   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
   dos.writeUTF(username.getText());
   dos.writeUTF(password.getText());
   ```

   ```
   inputStream = s.getInputStream();
   DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

   String username = dis.readUTF();
   String password = dis.readUTF();
   ```
2. you could write out a unique character sequence that will never appear in the string values themselves, such as a line break or control character (even a null terminator).  The reader can then read bytes until it encounters that sequence:

   ```
   OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
   String s;

   s = username.getText();
   writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
   writer.write(10);

   s = password.getText();
   writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
   writer.write(10);
   ```

   ```
   inputStream = s.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

   String username = reader.readLine();
   String password = reader.readLine();
   ```

   Alternatively:

   ```
   OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
   String s;

   s = username.getText();
   writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
   writer.write(0);

   s = password.getText();
   writer.write(s, 0, s.length());
   writer.write(0);
   ```

   ```
   inputStream = s.getInputStream();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   int ch;

   do
   {
       ch = reader.read();
       if (ch <= 0) break;
       sb.append((char)ch);
   }
   while (true);
   String username = sb.toString();

   sb.setLength(0);
   do
   {
       ch = reader.read();
       if (ch <= 0) break;
       sb.append((char)ch);
   }
   while (true);
   String password = sb.toString();
   ```

Comment: That's what i thought for a solution, but i thought maybe a better solution exists, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the propositions, i guess i'll take the third one!

Comment: These two (not three) approaches are the most basic fundamental ways of delimiting variable-length data during serialization. Either you provide the data's length beforehand, or you provide a marker to denote the end of the data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, i meant the second approach, the control character.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for `DataOutputStream` for writing and the `DataInputStream` for reading. With those, you can write an integer value before each String to know the length of the text, something like this:

```java
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);
dos.writeInt(username.getText().length());
dos.write(username.getText().getBytes());
dos.writeInt(password.getText().length());
dos.write(password.getText().getBytes());
```

And then, on the server side:

```java
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
int length = 0; // will be used to store the length of each text

length = bytesRead = dis.readInt(); // Read the length of the first text
byte[] usernameBuffer = new byte[length];
dis.read(usernameBuffer);
String username = new String(usernameBuffer);

// Now reading the other text
length = dis.readInt(); // Read the length of the second text
byte[] passwordBuffer = new byte[length];
dis.read(passwordBuffer);
String password = new String(passwordBuffer);
```